# How do I control the format MembershipUser.ResetPassword()

Tags: asp.net, passwords, asp.net-membership, reset

Is it possible to control the format of the password that is automatically generated by a call to MembershipUser.ResetPassword()?

I want to be able to allow or not allow certain special characters in the generated password.

I am using the SqlMembershipProvider with a password format of Hashed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to limit special characters? There's almost no defensible reason for this and is very user unfriendly.

Comment: @John Sheehan: On the other hand, I've had complaints from users that the generated password contains characters that are 'difficult to find'. Try telling a (non-programmer) user to find the | or ~ keys on the keyboard. Eliminating the hard-to-type characters can be considered a user-friendly move. Of course, you can tell the user to copy-paste the password, but I've met resistance with that as well.

Comment: You can generate easy to use passwords that are secure, but you shouldn't limit what people can use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this article - [Changing the autogenerated password format in the SqlMembershipProvider](http://www.sidesofmarch.com/index.php/archive/2006/10/16/changing-the-autogenerated-password-format-in-the-sqlmembershipprovider/).

> I came up with a quick way to hack the SqlMembershipProvider to generate less complex passwords, and it was as simple as creating a new provider class that inherits from SqlMembershipProvider, then overriding the GeneratePassword method.

This is not a fully resolved solution but it might help.

Answer (score 20):

You may want to do this in two steps, as identified by Mark Fitzpatrick here: http://bytes.com/groups/net-asp/689452-how-reset-users-password-without-having-use-passwordrecovery#post2740740

First Reset the password, then immediately change it to a format of your liking.  Obviously using a fixed string as in Mark's example would NOT be recommended - you'd want to implement [some random string generator](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS291US301&q=.net+random+string+generator&btnG=Search).

```
user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), MyMethodToGenerateRandomPassword());
```

Comment: I like your solution to it. I tried David HAust's solution, but when calling MembershipUser.ResetPassword(), it would still give me the mega-crypto passwords.

Answer (score 3):

Today you can also use the `Membership.GeneratePassword` method and pass a `MinRequiredPasswordLength`or use the property already defined in Web.config like this:

```
  var newPassword =
                   // 0 = Number of non alphanumeric characters
                  Membership.GeneratePassword(Membership.MinRequiredPasswordLength, 0);

  user.ChangePassword(user.ResetPassword(), newPassword);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was hoping that there would be some configuration setting could use but overriding the GeneratePassword() method works for my situation.

We already had a crypto utility class that would generate the random password strings so it was a pretty quick change.